# LibreOffice not auto-bookmarking heading

Tags: libreoffice, pdf-bookmarks

I have an .odt document converted from .docx, which I am trying to convert to a PDF. I want to have an auto-generated table of contents using my heading references, but when exported to a PDF, there are no heading references.

Essentially, I can't hyperlink to that heading, can't create table of contents entries based on headings, etc.

Is there any way, and what should I do, to automatically add bookmarks for each heading again?

Answer (score 0):

Check the PDF Export Options: On the "`General`" tab, the "`Export Bookmarks`" option has to be set:

[image]

To edit the options, use Menu "`File`" -> "`Export as PDF`".

Comment: The export bookmarks is set - the problem isn't limited to just PDFs; headings simply aren't automatically indexed.

Comment: Generating a Table of contents as well as creating pdf bookmarks for headings assumes that the heading`s paragraph style is one of the Heading styles (Heading1 up to Heading9). So you should check first which paragraph style is assigned to the headings.

Comment: I set the heading by applying the Heading 1 styles.